# How to get this format for resume (picture included)?

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to edit my resume under the skills section such that it is similar to the image posted below i.e. I am able to highlight each word.
[image]

I am using the moderncv template so mine will look slightly different. I think what I would like is to be able to put the brackets beside computer skills to indicate level of profiency just like the image above.

[image]

Comment: Can you please include a MWE to give us something to start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check whether the following code suits your requirement:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%% Personal data
\firstname{Firstname}
\familyname{Familyname}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\def\Grey#1{\textcolor{black!50}{#1}}
\begin{document}
%\makecvtitle

\section{Relevant Skills \normalsize(Expertise, \Grey{Proficiency})}
\cvitem{Languages}{C/C++, MATLAB, Python, \Grey{Java, Objective-C, Lua, Haskell}}
\cvitem{Software}{Blender, Maya, Photoshop}
\cvitem{Toolkits}{OpenGL, QT, FLTK, GLUT, \Grey{CUDA, GLSL, DirectX, Cocoa}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If the colour need to be changed to `blue` with `casual` theme, then:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%% Personal data
\firstname{Firstname}
\familyname{Familyname}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\def\Grey#1{\textcolor{black!50}{#1}}
\begin{document}
%\makecvtitle

\section{Relevant Skills \normalsize\textcolor{black}{(Expertise, \Grey{Proficiency})}}
\cvitem{Languages}{C/C++, MATLAB, Python, \Grey{Java, Objective-C, Lua, Haskell}}
\cvitem{Software}{Blender, Maya, Photoshop}
\cvitem{Toolkits}{OpenGL, QT, FLTK, GLUT, \Grey{CUDA, GLSL, DirectX, Cocoa}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]